# Does Perl optimize based on specific arguments, while parsing the source code?

Tags: perl, arguments, precompile

Is perl only checking for syntax errors during the parsing of the source code, or also doing some optimizations based on arguments/parameters?

E.g. if we run:

```
perl source.pl debug=0
```

and inside source.pl there is an if condition:

```
if ($debug == 1) {...} else {...}
```

Would the "precompilation/parsing" optimize the code so that the "if" check is skipped (of course assuming that `$debug` is assigned only at the beginning of the code etc, etc.)?

By the way, any idea if TCL does that?
Giorgos

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Optimizations in Perl are rather limited. This is mostly due to the very permissive type system, and the absence of static typing. Features like `eval` etc. don't make it any easier, either.

Perl does not optimize code like

```
my $foo = 1;
if ($foo) { ... }
```

to

```
do { ... };
```

However, one can declare compile time constants:

```
use constant FOO => 1;
if (FOO) { ... }
```

which is then optimized (constant folding). Constants are implemented as special subroutines, with the assumption that subs won't be redefined. Literals will be folded as well, so `print 1 + 2 + 3` will actually be compiled as `print 6`

Interesting runtime optimizations include method caching, and regex optimizations.
However, perl won't try to prove certain properties about your code, and will always assume that variables are truly *variable*, even if they are only ever assigned once.

Given a Perl script, you can look at the way it was parsed and compiled by passing perl the `-MO=Deparse` option. This turns the compiled opcodes back to Perl code. The output isn't always runnable. When `'???'` turns up, this indicates code that was optimized away, but is irrelevant. Examples:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e' "constant" '  # literal in void context
'???';
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e' print 1 + 2 + 3 '  # constant folding
print 6;
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e' print 1 ? "yep" : "nope" '  # constant folding removes branches
print 'yep';
```

Comment: Actually, `if( FOO ){` would become `if( 1 ){`. That is the limit of the optimization.

Comment: @shawnhcorey no, it actually compiles down to single, unconditional block, just try it out with `-MO=Deparse`. This is different from, but equivalent to an `if (1)`.

Comment: @amon Does Deparse actually do what the Perl compiler does, or is it actually doing these optimizations on its own? It is a module, after all.

Comment: @TLP, Deparse recreates the source code that was compiled by Perl. It doesn't parse or optimize anything. It's like `perl -MO=Concise`, but uses Perl to represent the ops.